# how to make a for loop for xpath in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, xpath

I'm trying to make a for loop to get all the data in the div, it did worked with one but didn't for the other
my code

```
  if(websearch != mainSearchUrl) { 
                     var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                    var doc = webGet.Load(websearch);
              
                    var webnode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]");
                
                      
                        foreach (HtmlNode node in webnode)
                        {
    
                        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
                        {
                            var title = node.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div["+i+"]/div/a");
                            var chapters = node.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]"); //here is the error when i put "i" instead of the pre last number it results null
                            comboBox1.Items.Add(title.InnerText + chapters.InnerText);// error chapters null
                        }
                            
                        }
```

Comment: Please only use the `[visual-studio]` tag for questions about Visual Studio.

Comment: oh i'm sorry didn't notice it was the main one

Comment: Can you provide the two lots of HTML you're testing against, since it seems likely (given your description) that the issue lies in the content being different in each?

Comment: https://bato.to/search?word=kaguya+sama ,in div id="item-title"

Comment: I solved it, it stopped at number 9 bec it was different , the last div was supposed to be div 3 for that number